# xml send by post to ashx handler.Some characters are send as "??",cant solve it

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, encoding, ashx

hello and happy easter,

I have 2 handlers an outer and an inner written in vb.net.
I use a test program in written c# to send an xml to the outer handler, and the outer handler sends the xml to the inner so i can store the xml to the database.

The test class code in c#
I am reading an xml and sending it via post to the url using request-response.

`FileStream READER = new FileStream("C:/Users/pantoniou.MAGR/Desktop/quote.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); //Set up the filestream (READER) //
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(READER);
                string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
                //WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://172.30.28.41/allianzservice/Handler1.ashx"));`

```
            //string value = "2000";
            //string date1 = "01-01-" + value;
            //DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(date1);

            //WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://bol.mondial-assistance.gr/allianzhttpouter/Handler1.ashx"));
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://172.30.29.2/allianzhttpouter/Handler1.ashx"));
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlcontents);
            Stream os = null;
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            os.Close();
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string sRet = "";
            sRet = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();`
```

the outer service code
here i get the xml for the first time and pass it via post to the inner handler.

`Dim stream = context.Request.InputStream
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length - 1) {}
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Dim xml As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)`

```
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.InnerXml = xml
    Dim xmlcontents As String = doc.InnerXml

    Dim webRequest1 As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri("http://172.30.28.41/allianzservice/Handler1.ashx"))
    webRequest1.ContentType = "text/xml"
    webRequest1.Method = "POST"
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlcontents)
    Dim os As Stream = Nothing
    webRequest1.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    os = webRequest1.GetRequestStream()
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    os.Close()
    Dim webResponse As WebResponse = webRequest1.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim sRet As String = ""
    sRet = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim()
    context.Response.Write(sRet)`
```

and the inner handler code

here i get the xml and deserialize it to an object

`Dim stream = context.Request.InputStream
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(stream.Length - 1) {}
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Dim xml As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)`

```
    context.Response.Write(xml)

    'Dim READER As New FileStream("C:/Users/pantoniou.MAGR/Desktop/quote.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(xml)

    Dim xmlcontents As String = doc.InnerXml

    Dim wrapper As [Interface]
    Dim ser = New XmlSerializer(GetType([Interface]), New XmlRootAttribute("interface"))
    Dim reader1 As New StringReader(xmlcontents)
    wrapper = DirectCast(ser.Deserialize(reader1), [Interface])`
```

so the problem is as i wrote before, that in the database most values are ok
and some values are stored as question marks "??"

I have tried messing around with encodings but with no help.
I know the problem is occures when i send the xml via the handlers.
I tried to read the xml directly from the inner handler and convert it to an object and store it to the database and it was ok.

Something happens when i send the xml via the handlers and i get those "??" in certain values.

Thank in front for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you reading bytes from file in ASCII mode

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlcontents);
```

change this to

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlcontents);
```

or

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlcontents);
```

---

Since you are only trying to upload file, i will suggest you to use [`WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String filePath)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) method

Try

```
var client = new WebClient();
byte[] response = client.UploadFile("http://172.30.29.2/allianzhttpouter/Handler1.ashx", "PATH TO UR XML");
```

Comment: I tried that and when i do change that to either utf-8 or default i get an error 500 as a responce and cant store anything to the database.

Comment: you are not creating proper post boundary as well, in general when files are uploaded, it uses multi-part post format, i dont see anything like that, that is why the error 500!

Comment: can u elaborate please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788877/what-is-a-multipart-http-post-and-how-to-make-it-scribd read this!